# Is the reputation correct, or is the user placed in the wrong place?

Tags: support, users

Looking at the list of users that show the total reputation, I noticed that this user is not in the right place; basing on his reputation, [Chris J. Lee](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/280/chris-j-lee) should be placed higher in the list.

[image: screenshot]

Maybe it's just his reputation that is wrong; I up-voted one of his answers, and his reputation went from 192 to 302; then I up-voted another of his answers (which I previously down-voted), and the reputation went to 314.

I checked again the user list in another tab of the same browser, and the user is now shown in a different place.

[image: screenshot]

Still, I am sure his reputation was initially 192.

Comment: I got it; the user has an account on other SE sites too; once he reached the reputation of 200, his reputation has been increased of 100 on Drupal Answers, and in the other SE sites.

Comment: The wrong position in the user list is simply caused by the fact the list is cached, by the browser, or SE software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce this, I upvoted an answer of a [user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/718/frederik) with 190 reputation. After that, he was in the same position in the list (between users with 192 and 182 rep respectively) but his reputation was shown as 300, both in the list as well as on his profile page.

Comment: Checking the user's reputation, it should be 200; the difference of 100 is because the user has reached the reputation of 200 on DA, and he has an account on another SE site. It's exactly what happened in my case too.

Comment: To be correct, that happens because the user didn't have any account with a reputation higher than 200 in any SE site; the user firstly reached a reputation of 200 on DA. Thank you, @marcvangend, for helping me to understand what was happening.

Comment: @kiamlaluno you're welcome, glad I could help. From my perspective I didn't even do that much - I didn't even know that the +100 bonus is only awarded if you have at least 200 rep on one of the SE sites...